# Convert to lower case specific words, contained in an array, whenever they appear in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I need to convert to lower case specific words, contained in an array, whenever they appear in a string.
For example:

```
var words = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'];
var string = 'This is the First chapter of the Second part of the Book XY by John Doe';
```

string should become: *This is the first chapter of the second part of the Book XY by John Doe*

How can I use `replace` and `toLowerCase()` to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to convert the list of strings into a single regex and replace them all in one sweep.

```js
let words = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'],
    rx = new RegExp(`\\b(?:${ words.join("|") })\\b`, "g"),
    string = 'This is the First chapter of the Second part of the Book XY by John Doe',
    transformed = string.replace(rx, s => s.toLowerCase());

console.log(transformed);
console.log(rx);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split it, map the words according to the words within the array, and finally join the transformed words into a string again.

```js
let words = ['First', 'Second', 'Third'],
    string = 'This is the First chapter of the Second part of the Book XY by John Doe',
    transformed = 
            string.split(/\s+/g)
                  .map(s => words.includes(s) ? s.toLowerCase() : s)
                  .join(" ");

console.log(transformed);
```

Comment: This won't work if a desired word is next to a punctuation character e.g. `First.`